# Problems display stored numbers in an array in a text box ascending

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

im having problems displaying the average values and numbers calculated in an text box.. when i click display button it only returns 0 0 values, i assume the problem is in my string reader but i dont know where im going wrong here is my code

```
  //initialising the array
            int numbers = counts;
            Array.Resize(ref scoreArray, numbers);

            //outputting and displaying the count in a text box
            for (int count = 1; count > numbers; count++)
            {
                scoreArray[count] = scores;
                txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
            }
        }

        //catch statement for displaying error message
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Please enter valid number ");
        }
    }

    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, scoreArray);
        MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);

        txtNumScores.Focus();
        txtCount.Clear();
        txtAverage.Clear();
        txtNumScores.Clear();
        txtTotal.Clear();
        counts = 0;
        total = 0;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo here: `for (int count = 1; count > numbers; count++)`. Didn't you mean `...; count < numbers; ...`?

Comment: What's your problem? **Has it been solved yet**? If not please try rephrasing it. In fact you use `1-based index` for your counter so I guess the loop condition should be `count <= numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int count = 1; count > numbers; count++)
            {
                scoreArray[count] = scores;
                txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
            }
```

to

```
for (int count = 1; count < numbers; count++)
            {
                scoreArray[count] = scores;
                txtCount.Text = count.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Jorge Córdoba thanks for your help dude, greatly appreciated the only problem with me changing > to < is that when i click button display the counter doesnt return correct average scores and the 1st number displayed is 0 and the rest are correct values

Answer (score 0):

it seems your entire for loop depends on the initial value of `int numbers = count;` and since 
`count = 0;` in btnDisplay_Click So the `number = 0;`and therefore  your for loop does not seem to execute at all,  So, you should cross verify the for loop condition as pointed by @Jorge above.